Match generic type: "Unbound" is not a class
I am trying to tell whether a variable is of type T using the syntax
match variable:
  case ClassName():

However, I get a "Unbound" is not a class error when using a generic. Why is T unbound?
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

class LetterList(BaseModel):
    letter: str

class NumberList(BaseModel):
    numbers: list[int]

class BulletPointsList(BaseModel):
    bullet: str


ListType = LetterList | NumberList | BulletPointsList | None

T = TypeVar("T", bound=ListType)

class ListPattern(Generic[T]):

    def test(self, list_type: T, other_list_type: ListType):
        match other_list_type:
            case T(): # "Unbound" is not a class
                pass
            case BulletPointsList():
                pass
            case _:
                pass

        # type(something_type) is a little confusing
        # edit: actually this doesn't work
        match type(other_list_type): 
            case T:
                pass


TypeVars cannot be used at runtime in such a manner, since it would refer to a special object, not a class.

The name T is bound to an instance of TypeVar at runtime. Only to mypy is it "bound" to the type of an argument of test.

This is because the python interpreter is not tracking, what generic type is used in instances and replaces the TypeVars used with the real types.
But there is a little workaround, we can do this:
def test(self, list_type: T, other_list_type: ListType):
    T_type: type = type(list_type)
    match other_list_type:
        case T_type(): # "Unbound" is not a class
            pass

or this should also work:
match type(other_list_type):
    case T_type:
        pass

Please note that as there is no description of what you want your code to do, I was not able to test this solution.
